# How to choose the number of nodes for using BP network in face recognition?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, backpropagation

I read some books but still cannot make sure how should I organize the network. For example, I have  pgm image with size 120*100， how the input should be like(like a one dimensional array with size 120*100)? and how many nodes should I adapt.

Comment: When it comes to the node count - there are no "correct" number of nodes to use. Your input should be a one dimensional matrix (vector). If you're able to cluster groups of image pixels and thus achieving a smaller image without losing too much information - it would speed up the learning process.

Answer (score 1):

It's typically best to organize your input image as a 2D matrix. The reason is that the layers at the lower levels of the neural networks used in machine perception tasks are typically locally connected. For example, each neuron of the first layer of such a neural net will only process the pixels of a small NxN patch of the input image. This naturally leads to a 2D structure which can be more easily described with 2D matrices.

For a detailed explanation I'll refer you to the [DeepFace](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~wolf/papers/deepface_11_01_2013.pdf) paper which describes the stat of the art in face recognition systems.

Answer (score 1):

120*100 one dimensional vector is **fine**. The locations of the pixel values in that vector does not matter, because all nodes are fully connected with the nodes in the next layer anyway. But you must be consistent with their locations between training, validating, and testing.

Answer (score 1):

The most successful approach so far was to go with a convolutional neural network with 2D input, just as @benoitsteiner stated. For a far simpler example I'd refer you to a LeNet-5, a small neural network developed for MNIST hand-written digit recognition. It is used in [EBLearn](http://eblearn.sourceforge.net/) for face recognition with quite good results.